# Large Print Siddurim

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, size, nusach-sefard

I am looking for a large print siddur in both Hebrew and English, preferably in Nusach Sefard. Does anyone know where I can find one or who prints such a siddur?

Comment: http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/PE6.html

Comment: heritage for the blind also has very large print available http://www.jewishheritage.org/sefard.html

Comment: @sam, it seems you have an answer. Might I suggest you post it as such?

Comment: look for what they call a "Chazan Siddur" or a "Shliach Tzibbur Siddur". Here's an example: http://www.nehora.com/siddur-bais-tefillah-p-u-shliach-tzibur-size/ --- or here: https://mekorjudaica.com/siddur-hebrew-only-sefard-chazan-size.html

Comment: @Menachem - Doesn't answer my question, because the siddurim you listed are all-Hebrew. I am looking for one with English.

Comment: @sam - It seems that they don't offer this siddur to just anyone. Only for those who are legally blind.

Comment: @sam - I am looking for one in Nusach Sefard, not Ashkenaz. The other listed large-type siddurim in Sefard are all-Hebrew.